# Checking if type == list in python

Tags: python

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
for key in tmpDict:
    print type(tmpDict[key])
    time.sleep(1)
    if(type(tmpDict[key])==list):
        print 'this is never visible'
        break
```

the output is `<type 'list'>` but the if statement never triggers. Can anyone spot my error here?

Comment: Have you used `list` as a variable somewhere? Beware that if you're working in the REPL or such it may still be re-defined from a while ago.

Comment: .....Woooowww... definitely a lesson regarding the shortcomings of softly typed languages. Wow...

Comment: Add it as answers and I'll accept. THANKS.

Comment: [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) and friends will help you out in the future (I wouldn't call this a shortcoming, really).

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Your issue is that you have re-defined `list` as a variable previously in your code. This means that when you do `type(tmpDict[key])==list` if will return `False` because they aren't equal.

That being said, you should instead use [`isinstance(tmpDict[key], list)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#isinstance) when testing the type of something, this won't avoid the problem of overwriting `list` but is a more Pythonic way of checking the type.

Comment: Nice. 'more Pythonic' is a wide concept.  just for the sake of education: [*what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 481):

You should try using `isinstance()`

```
if isinstance(object, list):
       ## DO what you want
```

In your case

```
if isinstance(tmpDict[key], list):
      ## DO SOMETHING
```

To elaborate:

```
x = [1,2,3]
if type(x) == list():
    print "This wont work"
if type(x) == list:                  ## one of the way to see if it's list
    print "this will work"           
if type(x) == type(list()):
    print "lets see if this works"
if isinstance(x, list):              ## most preferred way to check if it's list
    print "This should work just fine"
```

The difference between `isinstance()` and `type()` though both seems to do the same job is that `isinstance()` checks for subclasses in addition, while `type()` doesn’t.

Answer (score 29):

This seems to work for me:

```
>>>a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>>type(a)
<class 'list'>
>>>isinstance(a, list)
True
```

Answer (score 11):

Python 3.7.7

```
import typing
if isinstance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , typing.List):
    print("It is a list")
```

Answer (score 5):

Although not as straightforward as `isinstance(x, list)` one could use as well:

```
this_is_a_list=[1,2,3]
if type(this_is_a_list) == type([]):
    print("This is a list!")
```

and I kind of like the simple cleverness of that

Comment: This does not work in `python v3.9.15`

Comment: I was struggling with list type check for a while. You saved my time!