# Looping over a nested list in Python. Printing out individual letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am trying to get each elements out of the list, but for some reason, it is printing out each individual characters of each element within the list. How would I correct this?

My current code:

```py
import pandas as pd

myList = ["apple", ["banana", "blueberry"], "strawberry", ""]
myNames = ["Peter", "John", "Sally", "Craig"]

for x, y in zip(myNames, myList):
    decision = {"name": x, "fruit": y, "data": pd.DataFrame()}
    globals()[x] = decision

    for d, v in zip(myNames, myList):

        if len(v) > 1:
            for i in range(len(v)):
                print(v[i])
        else:
            print(v)
            d["data"] = v
```

Right now, it's output is:

```
A
P
P
L
E
```

I do not want this. I want `apple` to be a single element and go through the `else` clause. The only element that should go through the `if` clause is `['banana','blueberry']`

How would I do this?

Comment: `len('apple')` is **not** zero

Comment: What is `d['fruit'] = v` supposed to do?  `d` is a name (`str`) not a dictionary.

Comment: @MarkTolonen i changed it to `d["data"] = v`. Technically my code has calculations in it that lead to it being inputted into the data dict

Comment: `d` **isn't** a dict.  Post code that is indented properly, runs, and reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen made a typo in my code. Changed `main_dict` to `globals()` which should create different dictionaries

Comment: What's the point of `globals()[x] = decision`? It's irrelevant to your problem at hand, so you should just remove it from the code in your question. See [mre]

Comment: Since you want to iterate over `v` _only if it's a list_, you should _ask that question!_. Does this answer your question? [Checking if type == list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544091/checking-if-type-list-in-python)

Comment: Eh, for this instance you are probably correct

Comment: And `d` *still* isn't a dict and throws a `TypeError`.  Actually run the code you are posting.  As far as the main problem, change `if len(v) > 1:` to `if isinstance(v,list):` or change `'apple'`, etc. to `['apple']` so it is actually a 1-element list.

Comment: Also read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Your question would be much clearer if you show your expected output for _all_ elements of your `mynames` list

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten a multidimensional list to a single-dimensional list with the following recursive implementation that uses `isinstance` function to check whether a variable is of type list, allowing us to flatten lists with strings correctly:

```
myList = ['apple',['banana', 'blueberry'],'strawberry','']
def flatten(l):
    out = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i,list): 
            out += flatten(i)
        else: 
            out.append(i)
    return out
print(flatten(myList))
```

Comment: I think you had what i was looking for.

Comment: This would result in "Peter" correlating to "apple", "John" to "banana", "Sally" to "Blueberry", and "Craig" to "Strawberry". Is that what you wanted @worldCurrencies?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, that is exactly correct. I apologize for not having the correct terminology. Still learning python

Comment: @worldCurrencies That is not what your question would seem to indicate: in your question you said that you want to iterate over `v` and print individual values only if it's a list. Which would imply that you wanted `Peter => apple`, `John => banana, blueberry`, `Sally => strawberry` and `craig => <blank string>`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oh actually, your second comment was correct. I read too fast. The first comment was incorrect. The format of the second comment was correct